# How to center last two cards in bootstrap?

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4, angular-ui-bootstrap

[image]

I write application in angular, using bootstrap. I want the last 2 cards to be in the middle, instead of to the left. Now it looks like one last card is missing. I want to correct it. How to do it?

html code:

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top:1.1cm">
    <div class="card-columns">
  
      <div class="card text-center" [routerLink]="['/special/arrangements-salon']">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img [src]="salon" height="100" width="100"><br><label>
            <h5 style="padding-top:6mm">salon</h5>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="card text-center" [routerLink]="['/special/arrangements-study']">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img [src]="study" height="100" width="100"><br><label>
            <h5 style="padding-top:6mm">gabinet</h5>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
        
      <div class="card text-center" [routerLink]="['/special/arrangements-bedroom']">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img [src]="bedroom" height="100" width="100"> <br><label>
            <h5 style="padding-top:6mm">sypialnia
            </h5>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="card text-center"  [routerLink]="['/special/arrangements-kitchen']">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img [src]="kitchen" height="100" width="100"> <br><label>
            <h5 style="padding-top:6mm">kuchnia
            </h5>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
  
      <div class="card text-center" [routerLink]="['/special/arrangements-bathroom']">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img [src]="bathroom" height="100" width="100"><br><label>
            <h5 style="padding-top:6mm">łazienka</h5>
          </label>
        </div>
      </div>
  
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: card columns align card in a masonry style.

Comment: ah right then you cannot align the last two centre as it uses css columns and not flex - meaning the cards will be kept in their columns.  You probably want to change it back to `row` and use `justify-content-center` class,especially as you don't seem to need masonry as your cards are equal heights

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> add d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center to parent => card-columns div  or you can add mx-auto to last div

```html
  
        
<div class="container" style="padding-top:1.1cm">
        <div class="card-columns d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
      
          <div class="card text-center" [routerLink]="['/special/arrangements-salon']">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img [src]="salon" height="100" width="100"><br><label>
                <h5 style="padding-top:6mm">salon</h5>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
      
          <div class="card text-center" [routerLink]="['/special/arrangements-study']">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img [src]="study" height="100" width="100"><br><label>
                <h5 style="padding-top:6mm">gabinet</h5>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
            
          <div class="card text-center" [routerLink]="['/special/arrangements-bedroom']">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img [src]="bedroom" height="100" width="100"> <br><label>
                <h5 style="padding-top:6mm">sypialnia
                </h5>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
      
          <div class="card text-center"  [routerLink]="['/special/arrangements-kitchen']">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img [src]="kitchen" height="100" width="100"> <br><label>
                <h5 style="padding-top:6mm">kuchnia
                </h5>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
      
          <div class="card text-center" [routerLink]="['/special/arrangements-bathroom']">
            <div class="card-body">
              <img [src]="bathroom" height="100" width="100"><br><label>
                <h5 style="padding-top:6mm">łazienka</h5>
              </label>
            </div>
          </div>
      
        </div>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Bootstrap `card-columns` uses CSS multi columns and for various reason it's [not really possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41992140/how-to-center-single-column-in-css-multi-column-layout) to center items, or align rows differently.

Instead of using `card-columns`, use the grid (`row` > `col-*`), but you should note this won't give you a masonry layout or top-to-bottom ordering.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the previous answers didn't work for me. I am using Bootstrap 5.3.2. The .card-columns was dropped "in favor of Masonry", says the docs. See: [Migration to v5](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/migration/#card)

If you are still looking for another way to align the cards, here is layout using flex. Just replace content with actual cards.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/assets/css/docs.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body class="p-3 m-0 border-0 bd-example bd-example-flex">

    <!-- Example Code -->
  <div class="container d-flex justify-content-center" style="height: calc(100vh - 150px)">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
      <div class="row ">
        <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-3 justify-content-center">
          <div class="p-2 m-2">Flex item 1</div>
          <div class="p-2 m-2">Flex item 2</div>
          <div class="p-2 m-2">Flex item 3</div>
        </div>
        <div class="d-flex flex-row mb-3 justify-content-center">
        <div class="p-2 m-2">Flex item 4</div>
        <div class="p-2 m-2">Flex item 5</div>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
    
    
    
    <!-- End Example Code -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question is specifically about bootstrap 4, not 5, as can be seen on the tags on the original post. Perhaps you meant to post your answer on a bootstrap 5 question?

Comment: I mentioned the version of Bootstrap in my answer.

Comment: On a question about a completely different version of bootstrap.